# How do I add Python packages with compiled binaries to my deployment package and make the package compatible with Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, aws-lambda, pip, cryptojs

I've been trying to deploy a Python AWS Lambda function that depends on the cryptography
package, and I'm using a Lambda layer to include this dependency. Despite following recommended practices for creating a Lambda layer in an ARM64 architecture environment, I'm encountering an issue with a missing shared object file for the cryptography package.

Environment:

Docker Base Image: amazonlinux:2023

Python Version: 3.9

Target Architecture: ARM64 (aarch64)

AWS Lambda Runtime: Python 3.9

Package: cryptography

Steps Taken:

Pulled and ran the Amazon Linux 2023 Docker container.

Installed Python 3.9 and pip, and updated pip to the latest version.

Created the directory structure /home/packages/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages
in the container to mimic the AWS Lambda Python environment.

Installed the cryptography package (among others) using pip with the --platform manylinux2014_aarch64 flag to ensure compatibility with the Lambda execution environment.

Created a zip file my_lambda_layer.zip from the /home/packages directory.

Uploaded the zip file as a Lambda layer and attached it to the Lambda function, ensuring that the architecture was set to ARM64.

When invoking the Lambda function, I receive the following error:

```
{ "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "07fc4b23-21c2-44e8-a6cd-7b918b84b9f9", "stackTrace": [] }
```

This error suggests that the _rust.abi3.so file from the cryptography package is either missing or not found by the Lambda runtime.

Questions:

- Are there additional steps required to ensure that the shared object
  files from the cryptography package are correctly included and
  referenced in the Lambda layer?

  Is the manylinux2014_aarch64 platform tag sufficient to guarantee
  compatibility with AWS Lambda's ARM64 environment, or should another
  approach be taken for packages with native bindings like
  cryptography?

  Could this issue be related to the way the zip file is created or
  structured, and if so, what modifications are necessary?

Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!